# xampp setting up virtual hosts on mavericks

Tags: xampp, vhosts

I have installed xampp on my mavericks, I have come through the configuration of virtual hosts even when I thought I would do it by myself, but it still doesn't work. I can't find the problem anywhere, I have looked in all files that could have something to do with it, rewritten the `/etc/hosts` file the `../xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and the `../xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf` but when I go to browser and I type my vhosts specified address it doesnt work, it throws me a google search. I also tried to add another vhost but the same happens.

My vhosts file looks like this:
    NameVirtualHost *:80

```
# localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName "localhost"
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Allow From All
    Order Allow,Deny
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>


# My custom host
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName "site1.local"
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1"
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog "Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1/site1.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also added this line to the bottom of the hosts file:

```
# XAMPP VirtualHost mappings
127.0.0.1 site1.local
```

And uncommented the line in httpd.conf

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have disabled the .htaccess file by renaming it to htaccess and commenting out all the stuff.

I really dont know what else to do and it still doesnt work :-/

I didnt forget to restart the apache server respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vhost file is missing backslashes. It should looks like:

> ```
> # localhost
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName "localhost"
> DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp"
> <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/">
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
>     AllowOverride All
>     Allow From All
>     Order Allow,Deny
> </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> # My custom host
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerName "site1.local"
> DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1"
> <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1/">
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
> ErrorLog "Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/site1/site1.local-error_log"
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

put to your browser 
`http://site1.local/`
and it should be working.